# How iterate over a List and check it against the Enum values with a Stream

Tags: java, enums, java-stream

I have a *list* and I want to find out if it contains **any other** elements than what I have in the `enum`.

I have this working:

```
boolean containsMyEnumCode(List<String> processCodes) {
    if (null != processCodes) {
        for (final String process : processCodes) {
            if (!(Arrays.stream(MyEnumCode.values()).anyMatch((p) -> p.name().equals(process)))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works, but how could I replace `for` loops with a stream, and have it in fewer lines?

Comment: Isn't your method wrongly named? If `containsMyEnumCode` returns `true` it means that the list contains an element which is not one of your enum codes. Therefore shouldn't the method be called `containsOtherThanMyEnumCode`?

Comment: Yes you are right, I mixed it up when I changed the method name to something more anonymous to post it here; the original name is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `null` check, you can use [`Stream.ofNullable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T)) (available from **Java 9** onwards) which will create a stream with a single element (list of processors) or empty stream. Apply `flatMap()` to turn it to a stream of strings. And then apply `anyMatch()` as a terminal operation which will determine whether at least *one process* in the stream matches with the given predicate.

**Note:** that condition `!Arrays.stream().anyMatch()` means that **none** of elements in the stream should match the predicate passed to the `anyMatch()`. And that is the meaning of the operation `noneMath()`. A change of the terminal operation will make the condition more readable by eliminating the need in **logical not** in front of it `Arrays.stream().noneMath()`.

Another improvement that is made to this code was inspired by suggestions from [**Holger**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) and [**k314159**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13963086/k314159).

Stream of enum constants `Arrays.stream(MyEnumCode.values())...` from the **original code** that is used in the condition discussed above has a performance overhead. Method `values()` creates an array of enum constants at every call. And it will be invoked for every element in the list. Therefore it makes sense to introduce a local variable that will store a `Set` of enum-names and check every element in the stream against this set.

Also as Holger pointed out *null-friendly* solution will disguise the problem. `anyMatch()` will return **false** in case of an empty stream and this result will be accepted as **valid** instead of raising **NPE**, and then this list can be stored somewhere and will cause problems in the future.

Since I'm providing two solutions here I've implemented one in such a way that it will raise an *exception* with a custom message, and another as being *null-friendly* by using `Stream.ofNullable()`.

```
public static boolean containsNonEnumCode(List<String> processCodes) {
    Set<String> names = getEnumNames(MyEnumCode.class);

    return Stream.ofNullable(processCodes)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .anyMatch(process -> !names.contains(process));
}
```

Solution for **Java 8** (*requested by PO in the comment*) implemented as *null-hostile* by using `Objects.requireNonNull()`.

```
public static boolean containsNonEnumCode(List<String> processCodes) {
    Set<String> names = getEnumNames(MyEnumCode.class);

    return Objects.requireNonNull(processCodes, "processCodes list in null")
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(process -> !names.contains(process));
}
```

The method below expects the `Class` of an enum as a parameter and generates a `Set` of enum names.

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Set<String> getEnumNames(Class<T> enumClass) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(enumClass).stream()
            .map(T::name)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Slight performance issue: `MyEnumCode.values()` creates a new copy of the array every time it's called. You might want to pull that out into a local variable.

Comment: You can use `EnumSet<MyEnumCode> codes = EnumSet.allOf(MyEnumCode.class);`, then, there’s not even a single copy of the value array (as all `EnumSet` instances share an array behind the scenes). I wouldn’t recommend any of the `null`-test variants. The cleanest policy is to disallow `null` for collections; if you want an empty list, use an empty list, not `null`. Rejecting `null` with an exception is easy to achieve, just don’t check it at all, `processCodes.stream()` will do the right thing. But you can also place `Objects.requireNonNull(processCodes)` at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @Holger I agree that mixing valid outcomes with cases when a method was called with invalid input is a vicious practice that leads to NPE in other places or to malfunctioning. The idea with `EnumSet` is also good and I used it as well, but indirectly. The source list is type `String`. Call of `valueOf` with a string that doesn't correspond to a name of enum constant will raise an `IllegalArgumentException` (and this method is meant to find such string). So I've decided to create a `Set` enum-names.

Comment: That’s a very good approach which can also serve as template for similar tasks. I didn’t suggest a set of names for this specific task, as `enum` types tend to have a small number of constants, so the time complexity doesn’t matter. But in general, the set lookup is preferable over a nested linear search.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `Optional.ofNullable` on the collection passed through as a parameter you could do something like this:

```java
 Optional.ofNullable(processCodes).stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .anyMatch(code -> Arrays.stream(MyEnumCode.values()).anyMatch(v -> v.name().equals(code)));
```